# Node JS - Headers error when trying to create PDF

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm following a tutorial on how to generate a PDF using React/NodeJS. The PDF is getting generated in my files but I'm getting a headers error which is preventing the GET request from working.

0] Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

The proxy is working fine. I'm guessing I haven't handle the ajax requests properly.

NODE

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');
const pdf = require('html-pdf');
const pdfTemplate = require('../../documents');

// PDFs

router.post('/create', [
    check('text', 'Text field is required').not().isEmpty()
], (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    const { text } = req.body;

    res.json(text);

    pdf.create(pdfTemplate(req.body), {}).toFile('result.pdf', (err) => {
      if(err) {
         return res.send(Promise.reject());
      }
        return res.send(Promise.resolve());
    });
});


router.get('/fetch', (req, res) => {
    return res.sendFile(path.resolve('result.pdf'));
});

module.exports = router;
```

REACT

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.handleForm = this.handleForm.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            text: ''
        }
    }
    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
    handleForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const body = this.state;

        axios.post('/api/pdfs/create', body)
            .then(() => axios.get('/api/pdfs/fetch', { responseType: 'blob' }))
            .then((res) => {
                const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                saveAs(pdfBlob, 'newPdf.pdf');
            })
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleForm}>
                <input type="text" name="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you ran the developer tools in chrome while hitting the endpoint you are having trouble with?  Generally this error arises if you have return the response to a client but then try to set headers on the client afterwards.  I would advise putting a break point in the endpoint and stepping through and seeing what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to make a GET request inside your POST request to fetch something that could easily have been returned by the POST request. You can try to ensure that the POST route in the server returns the pdf.

Then your ajax call would look like this

```
axios.post('/api/pdfs/create', body)
  .then(res => {
    const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    saveAs(pdfBlob, 'newPdf.pdf');
  })
```

Inside your the controller for your `POST` route, you can do this...

```
(req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
  }

  const { text } = req.body;

  pdf.create(pdfTemplate(req.body), {}).toFile('result.pdf', (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
      return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
    return res.json({
      text: text,
      result: result // this contains the pdf file that is generated.
    });
  });
}
```